# slide images with different times in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with some images

```
<div class="slides_container">
          <div class="slides">
            <img src="gif256/3.jpg" data-time="5000" class="myimg"/>
            <img src="gif256/4.gif" data-time="3000" class="myimg"/>
            <img src="gif256/5.gif" data-time="4000" class="myimg"/>
            <img src="gif256/6.gif" data-time="5000" class="myimg"/>
            <img src="gif256/3.jpg" data-time="3000" class="myimg"/>
          </div>
</div>
```

I want to slide this images with delay writen in data-time attribute. I use this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">              
$('.slides img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
  $('.slides :first-child').fadeOut()
     .next('img').fadeIn()
     .end().appendTo('.slides');},
  5000);
</script>
```

but this code slides images with same delay(5 sec). How can I use each image's data-time to scroll it?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and recursion instead of setInterval.

```js
$('.slides img:gt(0)').hide();
changeSlide();
function changeSlide(){
  var changeIn = +$('.slides :first-child').data("time");
  console.log(changeIn);
  setTimeout(function(){
   
    $('.slides :first-child').fadeOut()
     .next('img').fadeIn()
     .end().appendTo('.slides');
     changeSlide();
  }, changeIn);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slides_container">
      <div class="slides">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000000/fff" data-time="6000" class="myimg"/>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/333333/fff" data-time="2000" class="myimg"/>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/666666/fff" data-time="4000" class="myimg"/>
      </div>
</div>
```